# Correct script for creating bulk Distribution lists from CSV file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a bulk of distribution lists, as instructed on technet site.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-Bulk-create-6be6c82f#content

but i am encountering some errors while trying to work with the script they offered there.

This is my CSV

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZa0K.jpg

And this is the script of working with:

```
# Create Bulk Distribution Groupsmake  CSV file
Import-Csv "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PowerShell\CreateDistributionLists.csv" | foreach {
New-DistributionGroup -Name $_.name -DisplayName $_.displayname –Alias $_.alias -PrimarySmtpAddress $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled ([boolean] $_.RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled)}
```

when i launch the script, i get this error:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '->RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled'.
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-DistributionGroup], >ParameterBindingException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,New->DistributionGroup
>      + PSComputerName        : server.domain.com

Please Assist.

<<<< UPDATE >>

Edited script as suggested by Matias ( thanks buddy ).
Now i face the same error when launching.

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '->RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled:'.
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-DistributionGroup], >ParameterBindingException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,New-DistributionGroup

in the csv , im typing "false" or "FALSE" under the "RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled" column ,same as initially shown in the screenshot i attached.

To be RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled to always be false...that will do the work for me, if you can help me edit the script to always be false in this, that will be awesome also, aslong as it work.

for reference, here is the script the way i use it now:

```
# Create Bulk Distribution Groupsmake  CSV file
Import-Csv "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PowerShell\CreateDistributionLists.csv" | foreach {
New-DistributionGroup -Name $_.name -DisplayName $_.displayname –Alias $_.alias -PrimarySmtpAddress $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled:$([bool]::Parse($_.RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled))}
```

<<< UPDATE SEP-03-2019 >>>

i have changed the script as suggested here to the following:

```
# Create Bulk Distribution Groupsmake  CSV file
Import-Csv "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PowerShell\CreateDistributionLists.csv" | foreach {
New-DistributionGroup -Name $_.name -DisplayName $_.displayname –Alias $_.alias -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $false}
```

Still i  am getting the following error:

> [PS] C:\users\user\Desktop\PowerShell>.\CreateDistributionLists.ps1
>   A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '->RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled'.
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-DistributionGroup], >ParameterBindingException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,New-DistributionGroup
>      + PSComputerName        : server.domain.com

Any suggestion ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Parse the boolean value correctly with `[bool]::Parse()`, then bind it to the parameter name with `:`, like so: `-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled:$([bool]::Parse($_.RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled))`

Comment: i did as you said, no i am facing another error, see my edits above.

Comment: Leave out the colon `:` and replace that with a single space character: `-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $([bool]::Parse($_.RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled))`. Or, if as you say setting the `-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled` parameter always to be False is OK, then simply do `-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $false`. Note that [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/new-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps#parameters) say this param is valid as of Exchange Server 2016, Exchange Server 2019, Exchange Online, Exchange Online Protection

Comment: Hi, i stil get the same error, i checked and i am working with exchange 2010. do you have syntax that might work better with that version?

Comment: Any thoughts here?

Comment: I'm also at the same issue here @sj1986, would you be able to share the updated script please ?